# QGIS - Visualize GML with CSV metadata

Tags: qgis, csv, visualisation

I have a file with 3D building information (GML file with building id and coordinates).
Also, I have a CSV file with the same building IDs, coordinates (X-Y and Longitude Latitude), and additional values, e.g. the year of construction.

Now I would like to visualize the GML file (2D), e.g. the years of construction in colors (1900 red to 2010 green).
I have both files loaded in a project, but I can't get them linked and visualized. How do I get this to work?

I am new to QGIS and using QGIS 3.16 LTS.

Comment: Take a look at the processing tool 'Join attributes by field value'. The building ID colum will be your key on which to join the tables.

Answer (score 3):

You can also do a direct join without creating a new layer. One option is to use virtual layers, but in this answer **I recommend to just use a dynamic layer join**:

1. Right click your layer and choose "layer properties"
2. Go to "Joins"
3. Click the "small green plus symbol"
4. Setup your Join-Layer and Join-Fields (`buildingIDs` in your case)

[image]

You will now have the matching attributes from your second layer in your first layer.

To then visualize your result go to Symbology, choose a graduated renderer and your linked year field as column. Choose a nice color bar and click classify. Done.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Under 'Symbology' I cannot select any data of the CSV file.
If I create something under 'Joins' and press ok and then open the same window again, the join is gone. Should it be like this?

Comment: You may need to first  import the CSV as a layer (the first 2 screenshots of my answer)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to import your CSV as a Delimited Text Layer. Choose `No geometry (attribute only table)`.

[image]

[image]

Then use the Processing tool `Join attributes by field value`.

[image]

[image]

Define the field on which to join (in this example: `id`). If you want to join specific fields, select them using the `Layer 2 fields to copy` option.

[image]

The result will be a new vector layer with the CSV attributes attached

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But where did I find 'Processing tool Join attributes by field value'?

Comment: I have updated my answer with how to find it